# Solana RPC versioned transaction

Tags: transactions, web3.js, rpc, jsonrpc-api, send-transaction

The [library docs](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getTransaction) say that the function

```
sendTransaction(transaction: Transaction, signers: Signer[], options?: SendOptions): Promise<string>
```

has been deprecated. Instead, one should call sendTransaction with a VersionedTransaction i.e.

```
sendTransaction(transaction: VersionedTransaction, options?: SendOptions): Promise<string>
```

The constructor of a VersionedTransaction requires a [VersionedMessage](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/modules.html#VersionedMessage), but I couldn't find any information on how to generate a VersionedMessage.

Is there an example on how to use the sendTransaction() function call?

Answer (score 4):

Since `VersionedTransaction` are a fairly new, the docs and content for them is still in the works of being created. But, here is a snippet from an upcoming doc that explains how to create a `VersionedTransaction` with web3.js:

```
const web3 = require("@solana/web3.js");

// connect to the cluster and get the minimum rent for rent exempt status
const connection = new web3.Connection(web3.clusterApiUrl("devnet"));
let minRent = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(0);
let blockhash = await connection
  .getLatestBlockhash()
  .then((res) => res.blockhash);
```

Create an `array` of all the `instructions` you desire to send in your transaction. In this example below, we are creating a simple SOL transfer instruction:

```
// create an array with your desires `instructions`
const instructions = [
  web3.SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
    toPubkey: toAccount.publicKey,
    lamports: minRent,
  }),
];
```

Next, construct a `MessageV0` formatted transaction message with your desired `instructions`:

```
// create v0 compatible message
const messageV0 = new web3.TransactionMessage({
  payerKey: payer.publicKey,
  recentBlockhash: blockhash,
  instructions,
}).compileToV0Message();
```

Then, create a new `VersionedTransaction`, passing in our v0 compatible message:

```
const transaction = new web3.VersionedTransaction(messageV0);

// sign your transaction with the required `Signers`
transaction.sign([payer]);
```

You can sign the transaction by either:

- passing an array of `signatures` into the `VersionedTransaction` method, or
- call the `transaction.sign()` method, passing an array of the required `Signers`

> NOTE:
> After calling the `transaction.sign()` method, all the previous transaction `signatures` will be fully replaced by new signatures created from the provided in `Signers`.

After your `VersionedTransaction` has been signed by all required accounts, you can send it to the cluster and `await` the response.

```
// send our v0 transaction to the cluster
const txid = await connection.sendTransaction(transaction);
console.log(`https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${txid}?cluster=devnet`);
```

> NOTE:
> Unlike `legacy` transactions, sending a `VersionedTransaction` via `sendTransaction` does **NOT** support transaction signing via passing in an array of `Signers` as the second parameter. You will need to sign the transaction before calling `connection.sendTransaction()`.

Answer (score 2):

As the code states, a `VersionedMessage`is either a `Message` or a `MessageV0`, so you can create either of those types and use it as a `VersionedMessage` when creating your `VersionedTransaction`.